# This project is not authorized to use this API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places

one of my android taxi app im getting error message when requesting a ride from map. i can point pickup and drop-off location and then go to ride calculation it showing **"invalid Distance This API project is not authorised to use this API"**. as i enabled google map for android, google place for android and google direction API. but still getting same error. even i tried to enabled all other 17 api from google map, but still getting same issue.

Anyone can solve this issue ?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <application
    android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.custom.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_android_map_api_key" />

    <activity android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.acitivities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.acitivities.LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.acitivities.RegisterActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity android:name="com.prinsapps.vanittcustomer.acitivities.HomeActivity" />

    <service
        android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentMethodActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalFuturePaymentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentConsentActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.FuturePaymentInfoActivity" />
    <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />
```

**RequestFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    networkAvailable = getResources().getString(R.string.network);
    tryAgain = getResources().getString(R.string.try_again);
    directionRequest = getResources().getString(R.string.direction_request);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.request_ride, container, false);

    if (!CheckConnection.haveNetworkConnection(getActivity())) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), networkAvailable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    bindView(savedInstanceState);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!CheckConnection.haveNetworkConnection(getActivity())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), networkAvailable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (distance == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.invalid_distance), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (pickup_address == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.invalid_pickupaddress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (drop_address == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.invalid_dropaddress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (fare == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.invalid_fare), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (origin == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.invalid_pickuplocation), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (destination == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.invalid_droplocation), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String o = origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
                    String d = destination.latitude + "," + destination.longitude;
                    AddRide(SessionManager.getInstance().getKEY(), pickup_address, drop_address, o, d, String.valueOf(finalfare), distance);
                }
            }


        }
    });
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class));

        }
    });
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), PayPalService.class));
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

}

public void bindView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).fontToTitleBar(getString(R.string.ride_request));
    //((HomeActivity) getActivity()).toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.request_ride));
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    calculateFare = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_calfare);
    confirm = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm);
    cancel = (AppCompatButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    pickup_location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_pickup);
    drop_location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_drop);
    textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    txt_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
    txt_number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_number);
    txt_fare = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_fare);
    txt_vehiclename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_vehiclename);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);

    Typeface book = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/AvenirLTStd_Book.otf");
    title.setTypeface(book);
    cancel.setTypeface(book);
    confirm.setTypeface(book);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    pass = new Pass();
    if (bundle != null) {
        pass = (Pass) bundle.getSerializable("data");
        if (pass != null) {
            origin = pass.getFromPlace().getLatLng();
            destination = pass.getToPlace().getLatLng();
            driver_id = pass.getDriverId();
            fare = Double.valueOf(pass.getFare());
            drivername = pass.getDriverName();
            pickup_address = pass.getFromPlace().getAddress().toString();
            drop_address = pass.getToPlace().getAddress().toString();
            if (drivername != null) {
                txt_name.setText(drivername);
            }
            pickup_location.setText(pickup_address);
            drop_location.setText(drop_address);
            txt_vehiclename.setText(pass.getVehicleName() + "");
        }
    }
    overrideFonts(getActivity(), view);
    user_id = SessionManager.getInstance().getUid();

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        if (direction.isOK()) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
            myMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(getActivity(), directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(origin.latitude, origin.longitude)).title("Pickup Location").snippet(pickup_address).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)).title("Drop Location").snippet(drop_address).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin, 10));

            calculateDistance(Double.valueOf(direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDistance().getValue()) / 1000);

        } else {
            distanceAlert(direction.getErrorMessage());
            //calculateFare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            dismiss();
        }


    }


}

@Override
public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
    distanceAlert(t.getMessage() + "\n" + t.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n");
    //  calculateFare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    myMap = googleMap;
    requestDirection();
}

public void requestDirection() {

    snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, getString(R.string.fare_calculating), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar.show();
    GoogleDirection.withServerKey(getString(R.string.google_api_key))
            .from(origin)
            .to(destination)
            .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
            .execute(this);

    confirm.setEnabled(false);
}

private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/AvenirLTStd_Medium.otf"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void AddRide(String key, String pickup_adress, String drop_address, String pickup_location, String drop_locatoin, String amount, String distance) {
    final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("driver_id", driver_id);
    params.put("user_id", user_id);
    params.put("pickup_adress", pickup_adress);
    params.put("drop_address", drop_address);
    params.put("pikup_location", pickup_location);
    params.put("drop_locatoin", drop_locatoin);
    params.put("amount", amount);
    params.put("distance", distance);
    Server.setHeader(key);
    Server.post("api/user/addRide/format/json", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            try {
                if (response.has("status") && response.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.ride_has_been_requested), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).changeFragment(new HomeFragment(), "Home");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tryAgain, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tryAgain, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_occurred), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

        }
    });
}

public void calculateDistance(Double aDouble) {
    distance = String.valueOf(aDouble);
    if (aDouble != null) {
        if (fare != null && fare != 0.0) {
            DecimalFormat dtime = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
            Double ff = aDouble * fare;

            try {

                if (dtime.format(ff).contains(",")) {
                    String value = dtime.format(ff).replaceAll(",", ".");
                    finalfare = Double.valueOf(value);
                } else {

                    finalfare = Double.valueOf(dtime.format(ff));
                }
                dismiss();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            txt_fare.setText(finalfare + " " + SessionManager.getInstance().getUnit());

        } else {
            txt_fare.setText(SessionManager.getInstance().getUnit());
        }
    }
    confirm.setEnabled(true);


}


public void distanceAlert(String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.INVALID_DISTANCE));
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.mipmap.ic_warning_white_24dp);
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.RED);
    alertDialog.setIcon(drawable);


    alertDialog.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alert.cancel();
        }
    });
    alert = alertDialog.create();
    alert.show();
}

private void dismiss() {
    if (snackbar != null) {
        snackbar.dismiss();

    }
}
```

**MapView.java**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
    BindView(savedInstanceState);
    if (!CheckConnection.haveNetworkConnection(getActivity())) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.network), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //serverKey  = getResources().getString(R.string.google_android_map_api_key);
}

@Override
public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {

    try {
        if (direction.isOK()) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
            myMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(getActivity(), directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));
            loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(origin.latitude, origin.longitude)).title("Pickup Location").snippet(pickup_location).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(destination.latitude, destination.longitude)).title("Drop Location").snippet(drop_location).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin, 50));

    TextView distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    distance.setText("");


}

@Override
public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
    Log.d("direction fail", t.toString());
    loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    myMap = googleMap;
    myMap.setMaxZoomPreference(80);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            requestDirection();
        }
    });
    thread.start();


    Log.d("max", myMap.getMaxZoomLevel() + "");


}

public void requestDirection() {

    Snackbar.make(view, "Direction Requesting...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
            .from(origin)
            .to(destination)
            .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
            .execute(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
    //myMap.resetMinMaxZoomPreference();
}


public void BindView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).fontToTitleBar(getString(R.string.track_ride));
    mMapView = (com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    loader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_loader);
    loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            pojo = (PendingRequestPojo) bundle.getSerializable("data");
            pickup_location = pojo.getPikup_location();
            drop_location = pojo.getDrop_locatoin();

            try {
                String[] latlong = pojo.getPikup_location().split(",");
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]);
                String[] latlong1 = pojo.getDrop_locatoin().split(",");
                double latitude1 = Double.parseDouble(latlong1[0]);
                double longitude1 = Double.parseDouble(latlong1[1]);

                origin = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                destination = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString() + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "location error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    askCompactPermissions(permissionAsk, new PermissionResult() {
        @Override
        public void permissionGranted() {
            if (!GPSEnable()) {
                tunonGps();
            } else {
                getCurrentlOcation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void permissionDenied() {

        }

        @Override
        public void permissionForeverDenied() {

        }
    });

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tracking/" + pojo.getRide_id());
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Tracking tracking = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tracking.class);
            if (marker == null) {
                Log.e("Print",tracking.getStatus());
                marker = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(tracking.getDriver_latitude(), tracking.getDriver_longitude())).title(getString(R.string.driver)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)));
            } else {
                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(tracking.getDriver_latitude(), tracking.getDriver_longitude()));
            }
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    android.location.Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } else {
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        setCurrentLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + currentLatitude + " " + currentLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */
        Log.d("Error", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    Log.e("location", currentLatitude + "  " + currentLongitude);
    setCurrentLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

}

private void setCurrentLocation(final Double currentLatitude, final Double currentLongitude) {
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            if(usermarker==null){
                usermarker=myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Your Current Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.taxi)).snippet(likelyPlaces.get(0).getPlace().getAddress().toString()));
            }else {
                usermarker.setPosition(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude));
                usermarker.setSnippet(likelyPlaces.get(0).getPlace().getAddress().toString());
            }

            likelyPlaces.release();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
            getCurrentlOcation();
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}

public void getCurrentlOcation() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
}

public void tunonGps() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

        // **************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); // this is the key ingredient
        // **************************
```

Comment: yes provide all the api ect... and here i added AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: are you using web api ? and have you web api for map?

Comment: Can you confirm that the API Key you are using is generated in the project where you enabled those APIs?

Comment: Hi i enabled map for android, place for android and direction API. but i try to enable web api too but no any changes

Comment: @RickyCuarez how do you connect a project with an API key?

Comment: @Thufir The API Key is generated in your Project. This can be done on your GCP console under the credentials section: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials